# Why is this SQLquery in Matlab returning repeated records?

Tags: mysql, matlab

I used JDBC driver to connect to the mySQL DB in Matlab. The connection works. However, when I used following SQLquery in Matlab to get data:

```
SQLquery = ['SELECT * FROM db_XYZ WHERE Col_Name=' '''Col_A'''];
```

I got repeated (always three times) results shown as below:

```
1 Col_A CA SFO
1 Col_A CA SFO
1 Col_A Ca SFO
```

There is only one row of `"1 Col_A Ca SFO"` in the database table.

Why? Thanks...

Comment: How sure are you that there is only one row? Have the run the query elsewhere?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I checked and found out that there are repeated rows and  it repeats three times. I do not know why. I redo the table loading process from a csv file from phpadmin and came through an error. However, when I checked the table, the data is there and repeated three times. Donot know why.

Comment: I suggest you delete this question then, spend some time debugging your process that gets you the data as that is where the problem lies. You should strongly consider implementing a primary key as it will prevent this from happening. I highly recommend you do this.